# How to paste an already copied URL into a new tab Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have a website I am testing that automatically copies a URL and I need to paste that copied URL into a new tab, I have tried the below but this does not work. Any suggestions please? Also - the URL copied is different each time as it has a unique token

```
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "getLink").click()   << the URL is copied when you click this link
    self.driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','_blank');")
    new_tab = self.driver.window_handles[1]
    self.driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
    pyperclip.paste()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current workaround:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Click the link to copy the URL
self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "getLink").click()

# Open a new tab
self.driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.webfx.com/tools/url-opener/','_blank');")

# Switch to the new tab
new_tab = self.driver.window_handles[1]
self.driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)

# Find the address bar and paste the URL
urls = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#urls")
urls.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')

# Press Enter to open
address_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: This returns no such element when trying to run this line:
urls = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#urls")

Comment: @Charl92 Did you find a solution or do you still need assistance?

Comment: I still need assistance, doing some googling it appears you can't type into a newly opened tab URL with selenium? What I need to do is paste a URL which is automatically copied from the browser into a new tab and open it but I can't see any way to achieve this. I have tried the above and other suggestions but none are working

Answer (score 0):

You can just store output in variable from `pyperclip.paste()` and pass it as a string parameter inside `window.open`

```py
self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "getLink").click() 
result = pyperclip.paste()
driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{result}')")
```

Example of usage:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pyperclip

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2024-01-24.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick='myFunction()']"))).click()
result = pyperclip.paste()
driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{result}')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Your existing code here...

# Assume you have copied the URL from the website and stored it in a variable 'copied_url'
copied_url = "https://example.com"  # Replace with the actual copied URL

# Open a new tab
self.driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','_blank');")

# Switch to the new tab
new_tab = self.driver.window_handles[1]
self.driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)

# Set the clipboard content to the copied URL
pyperclip.copy(copied_url)

# Paste the URL into the address bar or any input field on the new tab
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='address_bar']").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
```

Comment: The copied URL is different each time as it generates a new token every time it's copied